# Spring AOP - exclude specific aspects?

Tags: spring-aop

I'm using Spring 3.0.5, and was wondering if it's possible, to somehow exclude aspect classes from being loaded that have been annotated with the @Aspect stereotype, but at the same time, include other aspect annotated classes? It seems to be an all or nothing if you're going the annotation route(which I am) I've tried looking at the  and  but can;t seem to find anything that hints at this.

The reason for this is that I have a central core library which contains aspects, but I may not want to include these aspects in every project I create using this central library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long time for an answer...

If you are using AspectJ annotations with Spring AOP and not AspectJ runtime or compile-time weaving then you're in luck.  Spring will only pick up @Aspect annotated classes if they're annotated with something like @Component as well.  Spring does not consider @Aspect a candidate for component scanning.  If you're using XML configuration, simply remove that bean from your config.

I would suggest NOT using component scanning that would hit a core library.  For example, if your app is com.example.myapp1 and your core library is com.example.corelibrary.* make sure your component scanning is looking at com.example.myapp1 ONLY and not com.example.

It is *not* safe to component scan outside of your app's base package because of this exact reason.  Pull in the individual aspects with an XML config for the bean.